# Loadtesting vs Threading in IIS 7 & .NET 3.5 SP1

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, .net-3.5, thread-safety

I am running IIS 7 with .Net 3.5 SP1

Can anyone tell me if this is thread safe since it keeps on failing under high load of users :

```
 private static void addQueryStringParameters(XElement inputs)
        {
NameValueCollection qs = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
XElement queryStringParameters = new XElement("QueryStringParameters");


                    foreach (string key in qs.AllKeys)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                               -- some code   qs[Key]
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                               -- some code

                        }
                    }

}
```

If it is thread safe then why else would it fail... ?

By the way, the exception that I get is: `object reference not set`.

Comment: What line do you get the exception on?

Comment: we dont really know, just an exception gets logged in the database.. with this method name..

Comment: So the log isn't coming from the code inside the catch block? And you're not throwing the error from there?

Comment: i am throwing the error there.. and it gets logged into the database from the same catch block ..

Comment: Ok. So why are you asking if it's thread safe? I'm assuming this is a web app. Are you using threads in it?

Comment: As you are only accessing request-local state this is safe. Probably, an NRE in the code you left out. How did you make sure that this can't be the case?